# Error: could not start the command, unable to compile

Tags: errors, compiling, texmaker

With already existing documents, texmaker works flawlessly. I can change and edit the document. However, when creating a new document, I am unable to do so since I receive this error. I have literally copied the "code" from here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Learn_LaTeX_in_30_minutes , just in case if something had changed and maybe the problem is me. But, to no avail, as I am still getting that error: "could not start the command. pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode%.tex". It is driving me mad, someone please help.

Here is a screenshot of both the "code" and the error: [image: Could not start the command. error]

Now I have tried following the fix that someone suggested in another post, and that was to simply run texmaker as an administrator, but that didn't work in my case - I'm getting the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your code in image works (please next time provide code /copy from editor/ , not its image)   just fine.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it can compile on existing documents? The error normally indicate that texmaker cannot find LaTeX at all.

Comment: daleif, I am able to compile existing documents, at least it appears I am able to.  For whatever reason, only creating new documents doesn't work, but I am able to edit pre existing ones, I am only missing the ability to create new ones (I have imported the document I am able to edit from a linux install so maybe that is why that single ones works). In either case, any ideas how I could resolve my issue? Or how would I locate LaTeX with texmaker?